# If an area remains at temperature 0 Kelvin would the area be frozen in time?

Tags: time, kinematics

If an area is at 0 kelvin, I am guessing that there is no motion. Without motion in an area, will it not look as if time has stopped?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temperature is not a fundamental property - it's an emergent property of ensembles of particles and is basically a measure of their relative kinetic energies. For example, you can't talk about the temperature of a single uranium atom because a single atom has no temperature. However once you have a mole of uranium atoms you can measure the energy stored in their relative motions and relate this to a temperature.

So since temperature isn't a fundamental property you shouldn't be surprised to find that zero temperature does not make a system time independant. For example even if you cooled a chunk of uranium to absolute zero the radioactive decay would still continue.

However cooling to absolute zero would stop any phenomena that rely upon scattering of particles from each other. So for example all chemical reactions would stop.